# Sublimerge on SublimexText2 gives error /bin/sh: git: command not found Exit code: 127 on OSX 10.8.5

Tags: macos, git, path, sublimetext2

I installed Sublimerge on SublimeText2, it was working fine until it started giving the following error

> /bin/sh: git: command not found  Exit code: 127

[image]

Git path on the computer has not been changed and git works as is. Not sure why then Sublimerge is unable to find the path.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The git location inside the sublimerge settings file was incorrect and after fixing, it started working correctly.